# Automatic Resume from a hibernate of a system running Windows 7 starter using perl

Tags: perl, hibernate, windows-7, automation

I have written some perl scripts to automate multiple test cases running in my client. My Client needs to hibernate or sleep multiple times and then wake up automatically during the excuetion of the test scripts. Is there any system command or any other way to automatically resume from a sleep or hibernate. I have a socket open in the client and a server has also been set up to send script names, order of excuetion etc.

Any ideas on this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the second computer [wake the client on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN).